# How to exit a process in sublime text 2 build and how to view the current build windows?

Tags: build, sublimetext2

When I run a build ctrl-B it shows up a console with the program running.

- But if I press esc it closes, how do I open it now?
- If I build again, how do I see the previous build console?

In my case I'm not building anything just starting a node.js process. And my workflow has a problem because if I build 2 times I have 2 node.js processes open, which is bad and doesn't work...

I would like to know at least how it's named the build-console, just to research and how can I view all the build-console opened?
Also I need to exit the node.js process, I don't know how to do it too.

**Update:**
Well I've managed to exit the process but I have a problem, if I run twice the build I still can't exit the first process...

What I really need, it's something that closes the last process and restarts...

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here. I would add a killall node line to my build system but I have no idea how to set up a second command in sublime...